# Combining queries that have the same data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database that was not built correctly and now I'm trying to retrieve data out of it. Basically I have 3 Maj Event Queries and I just need to "stack" the three queries on top of each other. I have run 3 queries to get all the field names to line up but now I am stuck. The three queries have the same fields but different data. I want to make all the queries appear as one. Query 1 has 45,213 records, query 2 has 16,492 and query 3 has 3,592 so I need a Summary query that has all 65,298 records in it. I hope this makes sense and thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you remove the `mysql` tag as this has nothing to do with that RDBMS.

Comment: Maybe the OP is trying to pull from a MYSQL db into an Access db?

Comment: OP says "I have an access database" "I'm trying to retrieve data out of it". If these are link tables to Mysql, MySQL is still a superfluous tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stacking" queries is called a "UNION". Assuming that each view has the exact same columns and each column is the same type, you write a union like:

```
 SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM query_1
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM query_2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT f1, f2, f3 from query_3;
```

Comment: The UNION query works, but maybe you want to go to the source tables of the query and look at the criteria used to develop the 3 different query views, and create a cleaner query that combines the criteria to look for all 3 "events"

Comment: "You should also refactor once you have all of this built and working the way you want" is always implied. In this case, if the source of the three queries is the same base tables, then write one query with a proper WHERE statement to select all of the data you need instead of UNION as UNIONs are much slower in that scenario. If the data in these three queries comes from seperate sources, then UNION is A-OK.